# terminology or design pattern name

Tags: c++, const-cast

I am reading a source code in which there is a class definition as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class C {
    ...
    T * func() {
        const_cast<C *>(this)->somefunc();
        ...
    }
};
```

I am unable to understand the philosophy or purpose of this syntax. What is this and what is the application of such code? I would like to know the formal terminology/definition or design pattern for the same.

**EDIT:**

`somefunc()` is implemented as follows:

```
void somefunc() {
    anotherfunc(*this);
}
```

and `anotherfunc()` is:

```
template<typename T>
inline void anotherfunc(C<T> & a)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("blah blah blah")
                             + typeid(T).name());
}
```

Then within the code there are classes like:

```
class F {
    func_1();
    func_2();
    func_3();
}
```

`C` is instantiated like this:

```
C<F> inst;
```

then the functions within `F` are accessed `inst->func_1();`.

Comment: well, only somefunc() from `C` would be called in any derived class, even if overrides are available

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux yes but why would someone want to do this? Is there any particular use where this is beneficial? Is this a design pattern? I've not seen something like this before.

Comment: I believe the general name for this is the `const_cast hack`.

Comment: the design pattern that comes to mind is "doing it wrong" but it would be useful to know what `somefunc()` is actually doing.

Comment: @Shep I've added more code.

Answer (score 0):

If one were aiming to redirect an API to use an existing API, without forcing the client to change code.

IF you could provide more context about

- somefunc() declaration.
- Any class hierarchy.

to help us identify the real need.

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern is called Dependency Injection.

Comment: Huh?! Always thought DI is where you don't construct subobjects yourself, but rely on someone to construct it and pass it to you